# Any one faced document sequence problem with adempiere?"

Tags: adempiere

Any one working with adempiere faced an issue that, when any window opens  a default value '5567' appears in DocumentNo field. Couldn't understand the cause and the solution!

Comment: HI Arzu, can you add a bit more detail? Which document and which version of the software are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, solved the problem, actually no default value was set, and document sequence was not working, just found that preference value was set for that column unconsciously by a user. that was done by right clicking on the field and he selected preference Ok, then a value for that column in every window was set. By deleting the record, problem gone away.

Comment: A user's _Role_ has a **Preference Level** defined.  Possible choices for the preference level are; _None_, _Client_, _Organisation_ or _User_. You can use this to determine what level, if any, in your organisation that you will allow a user with this role to set preference values.

Answer (score 1):

If you are seeing a default value when you look at a new record, be it a document or otherwise, check the following:

- the default value can be set by the Table/Column using a specific value or logic expression.
- the database may be applying a specific value
- A callout or script may be setting the value

If the record has been saved then look at

- The document sequence for that document type/table
- BeforeSave() functions in the model
- Any model validators that would affect the document or table